# Присоединение кириллицы к латинице (и другим иноязычным конструкциям) при помощи апострофа

Tags: орфография, грамматика, дефис, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

Существует такое правило (см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/#:%7E:text=%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8,%5D%2C%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20A.)).

> Апострофом отделяются русские окончания и суффиксы от предшествующей части слова, передаваемой латинскими буквами, напр.: *Он инструментовал сочиненную летом с moll’ную увертюру* (Берб.); *французский перевод обоих романов* [Ильфа и Петрова], *выполненный и аннотированный A. Préchac’ом* (из комментария к современному изданию романов); *пользоваться E mail’ом.*

Но есть вопросы. Как присоединить к латинице частицу (суффикс), которая пишется с кириллицей через дефис ("то", например)? И как присоединить кириллицу к НАЧАЛУ латиницы (приставку, скажем)? Подчеркну, что такая необходимость есть, то есть в некоторых книжных случаях заменять латиницу на кириллицу — не вариант, важно её оставить (!).

1. *В Amara(-/')то номера получше будут, чем в этом не пойми что.*

По идее, тут бы поставил апостроф, ведь "то" здесь как бы превращается в суффикс, и надо просто следовать вышеупомянутому правилу. "В Amara'то..." Верно?

2. *С Twitter'ом(-/')то что делать будем? Закрыли его, кажись.*

По идее, тут бы поставил дефис, поскольку частица "то" присоединяется уже к русскоязычному окончанию "ом", а не непосредственно к слову латиницей. "С Twitter'ом-то..." Верно?

3. *Этот наш псевдо(-/')Facebook никому не нужен.*

По идее, тут бы поставил апостроф, следуя по аналогии правилу, хотя в нём про приставки не говорится. "Этот наш псевдо'Facebook..." Верно?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила и согласилась с моими вариантами, хотя, похоже, готового однозначного решения у них нет (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309740)).

> Иностранные названия в русском тексте лучше передавать кириллицей, тем более два из приведенных Вами названия (*Твиттер* и *Фейсбук*) графически уже освоены русским языком. Если все же по каким-то причинам названия необходимо передать латиницей, то предложенные Вами варианты оформления можно принять: апостроф лучше покажет границу между собственно названием и русской морфемой, чем дефис.

Comment: Я бы во всех случаях, где по правилу русского языка требуется дефис, рекомендовал ставить дефис. Апостроф выглядит максимально неуместно. Замечу, что названия *твиттер* и *фейсбук* уже достаточно прочно вошли в русский язык, чтобы писаться кириллицей. *Твиттер* вообще есть в орфографическом словаре.

Answer (score 1):

Не существует правила, согласно которому дефис можно было бы заменить апострофом. Поэтому об этом речи идти не может.

Апостроф должен располагаться именно между иностранными и русскими знаками. Все три символа в "-то" принадлежат к русскому языку, а потому нет оснований дробить их апострофом и относить дефис к половине, которая принадлежит иностранному слову.

Обратите внимание, что в правиле, которое вы приводите, не говорится ничего о постфиксе. А "то" как раз является не окончанием или суффиксом, а постфиксом, который отделяется от предшествующего слова дефисом. При этом нет никаких указаний на то, каким может быть это слово (сколько в нём внутренних дефисов, апострофов и т.д.). Отделяется именно постфикс. Это означает, что ему всегда предшествует именно дефис, независимо от особенностей предстоящего слова. Отсюда я нахожу единственно верным вывод о том, что конструкция "-то" неразрывна и не зависит от контекста. Для иллюстрации этой идеи я напомню вам, что именно таким образом оформляются ситуации с кавычками, в которых конструкция "-то" всегда ставится уже после. А что такое апостроф, как не такая же кавычка, которая в большинстве случаев должна вписываться в язык по похожим правилам.

Отсюда логичным решением выглядит: Amara'-то

Однако налицо перегруженность пунктуацией. Апостроф помогает нам показать точку в слове, где иностранная речь превращается в русскую. В нашем примере слово "Amara" представляет монолит, за которым нет букв, нуждающихся в графическом обособлении. Дефиса читателю в данном случае достаточно. Так что лучшим вариантом можно считать: Amara-то.

Для того чтобы помочь читателю лучше воспринять фразу, я бы предложил выделить иностранное слово курсивом, а "-то" оставить как есть. Это наиболее изящный вариант.

Если же слово в своём монолите включает элементы двух языков, логично использовать и дефис, и апостроф, как в вашем примере: Twitter'ом-то.

Что касается последнего вопроса, то "псевдо-Facebook" следует писать через дефис, поскольку правилами регламентировано дефисное написание перед прописной буквой в именах собственных. То, что имя собственное написано латиницей, никак на правило не влияет. Кроме того, обратите внимание, что апостроф указывает на своеобразную усечённость слова, некоторую линию среза гипотетического иностранного окончания (которого, естественно, не существует, но всё же), на замену которому предлагается русское окончание. Поэтому апостроф и ставится в конце. Приставка не является усечённой частицей слова. Она вполне самостоятельна и полноценно выполняет свою смысловую функцию. Так что "обрубать" там нечего.