# Сверх-Turm / сверхTurm

Tags: орфография, дефис, правила, сложные-слова

У меня есть моё новое правило, т. к. ни один кот ещё об этом таки не думал! Думаете, оно правильное?

Оно заключается в том, что, когда мы приставку, написанную по-русски, или префиксоид, прибавляем к слову, не по-русски написанному, нам надо дефис использовать всегда, напр.: *Kamel – пол-Kamel'я, quince — полу-quince, persimmon – полу-persimmon, jackal – недо-jackel, beacon – супер-beacon, Turm – сверх-Turm.*

Comment: Готового правила нет, но "Грамота.ру" в таких случаях всё же рекомендует апостроф (задавал похожий вопрос): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470921/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8

Comment: смысл использовать русскую приставку и русскую грамматику с латинским словом? Используй английские: half- , super-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лопатин:

> [**§ 151.**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80) Недопустимы слитные написания с одной прописной буквой в середине слова. Поэтому после начальной части слова, по основным правилам пишущейся слитно, — после приставки, первой части сложного или сложносокращенного слова — следует писать дефис, если вторая часть представляет собой собственное имя и потому пишется с прописной буквы.
> Примеры: *анти-Маяковский, архи-Плюшкин, не-Россия... полу-Африка, микро-Чернобыль... пол-Байкала, пол-Грузии...*

Розенталь:

> [**§ 41.**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm) <...> **Примечание 1.** На общем основании слитно пишутся иноязычные приставки ***анти-, архи-, гипер-, интер-, инфра-, контр-, пост-, суб-, супер-, транс-, ультра-, экстра-*** и др., например: ***анти**народный* (но: ***Анти**-Дюринг* – в функции собственного имени)... ***супер**обложка* (но: ***супер**-ЭВМ* – перед прописной буквой)...
> **Примечание 2.** Слитно пишутся начальные составные части ***квази-, псевдо-, пан-***, например: ***квази**научный, **псевдо**классический, **пан**германский*** (но: ***квази**-Пушкин, **пан**-Европа* и т. п. – перед собственными именами).
> ** Исправлено слово "пангерианскин" на "пангерманский" (Р. М.).

Как недопустима прописная буква в середине слова, так недопустимо и использование двух языков в одном слове. Поэтому — используя подсказки, все-таки уже имеющиеся в правилах, — пишем особые слова **через дефис** (тем самым разделяя "разноязыкость") и выделяем написанное на другом языке **курсивом** (как рекомендуется при использовании апострофа):
пол-*Kamel*'а (я бы написала окончание **-а**), полу-*quince*, полу-*persimmon*, недо-*jackel*, супер-*beacon*, сверх-*Turm*.